# X-Requested-With/HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH weird problem

Tags: django, cherokee

I'm building a Django site and trying to use the `request.is_ajax()` function... But **it's only working *locally*** and it's driving me crazy!

I'm at the point where I've just dumped the headers. Here (on the django test server) there's `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` but on the production server (cherokee+scgi) all I get is `X-Requested-With`.

I've used firebug to snoop the *sent* headers and it's `X-Requested-With` (on both versions of the site). I'm very, *very* confused. Can anybody explain what's happening and how I can work around it without losing my mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrt/ the X-Requested-With => HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH stuff, it's in conformance with the CGI specifications. Since FastCGI, SCGI and WSGI are all based on the CGI specs, Django developpers choosed to stick to this convention (FWIW, the ModPythonRequest class do the same rewrite for consistency).

So it seems that your problem is that something in the cherokee/scgi chain doesn't rewrite the headers correctly. Which scgi implemetation are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working around the issue with a tiny bit of MiddleWare that essentially looks for the "wrong" header and if it exists, appends a new header of the same value:

```
if 'X-Requested-With' in request.META:
    request.META['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = request.META['X-Requested-With']
```

But I really wish I knew what was supposed to happen with these headers because `X-Requested-With` is always sent... I don't see why that should be translated in to `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` and why it's not.

Edit: The cause appears to be deep within the actual web server.

```
case 'X':
    if (header_equals ("X-Forwarded-For", header_x_forwarded_for, begin, header_len)) {
        ret = add_known_header (hdr, header_x_forwarded_for, val_offs, val_len);
    } else if (header_equals ("X-Forwarded-Host", header_x_forwarded_host, begin, header_len)) {
        ret = add_known_header (hdr, header_x_forwarded_host, val_offs, val_len);
    } else
        goto unknown;
    break;
```

I've filed a bug to get my header added but should all X-* headers be converted into HTTP_X_* headers?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's up to the webserver to translate HTTP headers into the SCGI environment.  Don't know how this is supposed to happen in SCGI (I use WSGI), but this might be a bug in Cherokee.